# WebRTC Requires a Specific Signaling Server Software?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I know [easyRTC](https://easyrtc.com/) and there is more software like that, I can install it on my VPS to accept WebRTC technology.

But do I really need it?

I am still learning...

I have virtual shared hosting server, that has node.js installed and I can use it on my control panel and also use some port forwarding and WebSockets.

Is it possible to make signaling server with this shared hosting server for WebRTC video calls, chat rooms or should I stop wasting my time with this. 
(Like upload and run it with node.js etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes - you can use your own server's websockets for signalling. The simplest would be:

```
socket.on('message', function(msg){
  io.to('roomid, socketid etc').emit('message', msg); // here you send msg to other user / users
});
```

But the harder (comparing to libraries like easyRTC) thing starts when you want to use it on frontend. But [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/) you can find some nice examples depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, You are right it's a pretty hard to understand and modify the code to implement with my server (at least people who have 2 days of experience with WebRTC and other technology needed for it), but still there seems to be some good stuff that I would like to understand. Basically what I am currently interested in is one on one video calls +everything else in the future. There are so... many examples and ways for everything. Any directions would be appreciated. At least now I know that it's possible.

Comment: I managed to create hybrid app (mobile - Android / iOS based on ionic / cordova and web app - Firefox, Chrome) that work together. It was one on one audio / video communication. I also used my own signalling server (sockets, the same connection as text chat). Unfortunately it is copyrighted so I can't show you exact code. Hopefully in couple months I'll post some examples to github.